# Can I refer to a DIV id or class in a PHP file from a HTML page?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to add my own custom contact form to a Blogger website project. I've got the contact form HTML code in the Blogger template and its own PHP file running on a server, which link I point to the form tag action. It sends email and both platforms seem to communicate well. Among many improvements I am currently making. My main concern is to learn how to send HTML formatted emails. Everytime a user submits a message, I would like to receive it in HTML format. The CSS below is meant to test this feature which later I will develop.

UPDATE:

```
    <?php
    ...
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    
    if ($_POST['Submit']) {
       if (empty($_POST['Phone'])) {
        $content = "<html>
              <head></head>
              <body>
                <div class='boldtext'>From:</div>
                $name
                <br/>
                <div class='boldtext'>E-mail:</div>
                $email
                <br/><br/>
                $message
               <style>
                 .boldtext {
                    font-weight: bold;
              }
              </style>
              </body>
              </html>";
if (mail ($to, $subject, $content, $from, $headers)) {
      echo '<div class="boldtext">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
   } else {
      echo '<div class="messageerror">An error has occurred. Try again later.</div>';
   }
}
```

The email client receives the email as plain text instead of HTML formatted though.

Comment: If you have access to the PHP file that generates the form then there should be no problem to add to the content.

Comment: I have access to to it, I made it. I'll post the code. It already sends the messages, even though validations and limits are not fully working yet.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is when you have full access. What do you want to add?

Comment: you can directly wrap above code in `<html>` tags. (i.e. `<html><head><title>Untitled</title></head><body><?php Your code Here ?></body></html>`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) and [here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/)

Comment: I would like to be able to send a html formatted email. I know I can do it with headers, but I am new to PHP and not sure how to do it. Then I would like to make the echos show directly in the form replacing the input placeholder. But I am pretty sure that's more complicated than this as I need ajax.

Comment: Thank you, fusion3k, and would it still work as a PHP form action if I wrap it in html tags?

Comment: Yes. Validate the output to ensure valid HTML. I suggest you to spend some time reading basic tutorials to better understand php behavior.

Comment: Yes, I probably should, just didn't have the time and didn't find the right ones. I found this and its approach is not really similar: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php

Comment: Keep in mind not all email programs act the same way. Take a look at this overview https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Your current code example is missing closing tags for `body` and `html` and the closing `";` for the string and definition of `$content`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but that was for copy pasting, I tried it with closing tags, and the email is not recognized as HTML format, it just comes through as plain text.  Anyway, your answer is good and I've been changing many things on the code and will have to open a new question for that, so I am choosing your answer as correct, because it is. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email will be like an HTML page as displayed on the WWW. You can use every element the same way.

Something like:

```
$content =
        "<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div class='title'>My Title</div>
            ...
            <div class='end'>Best Regards</div>
            <style>
             .title {
             color : blue;
             }

             .end {
               color : green;
             }
            </style>
          </body>
        </html>";
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Where should I paste this code? I am trying to make some changes like making some sections of the $content variable such as "From:", etc. bold before trying to make an email template. How could I refer to that variable sections?

Comment: if you want to take care of things using CSS you will have to add classes to the sections for example `<div class='myclass'>` when filling the `$content` variable.

Comment: Keep in mind when people have set their email program to show all email in plain text, none of your styling will show up.

Comment: You won't believe me, I've so many hours awake, that I completely omitted the beginning of your code... By the way, why header instead of head? Am I missing something?

Comment: I actually edited the code to make it match your scenario better. And... I made a mistake, typo, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated the question. Unfortunately the issue is not reserved to $content. Something is failing when it comes to the HTML format for the email I received and it can't be the service provider as I receive numerous newsletters reading HTML content. Maybe I am wrong, but I do think it's active. Outlook supports style tag in head or body. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/